# Can I use post thumbnail as cursor image when hovering over post link? (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, cursor

i'm too new to javascript, php and wordpress to figure this out myself, so maybe someone can help me.

i'm making a portfolio page on wordpress. all post titles are in a loop in a sidebar.php file.  i want to make it so that when you hover over the post's title, the cursor changes to the post's featured image/post thumbnail.

the most common result of googling is the simple css version, something like this:

```
.sidebar {cursor:url('img.png') auto}
```

so i had this:

```
.sidebar a:hover{
    cursor:url('<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){
    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');}?>') auto;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed;
    border-color: blue;
```

but it doesn't work. the php works when put in any of the php files, sidebar.php for example, the thumbnail is then under the post title.

another option i found was a javascript one, it was on this page:

http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-create-custom-image-cursors.html

```
#test-area {
height: 200px;
border: 3px dashed #CCCCCC;
background: #FFFFFF;
padding: 20px;
cursor: url(./blank.cur), none;
}

#mycursor {
cursor: none;
width: 97px;
height: 137px;
background: url("images/custom-cursor.jpg") no-repeat left top;
position: absolute;
display: none;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 10000;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test-area').mouseout(function(){
        $('#mycursor').hide();
        return >false;
    });
    $('#test-area').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#mycursor').show();
        return >false;
    });
    $('#test-area').mousemove(function(e){
        $('#mycursor').css('left', e.clientX - 20).css('top', e.clientY + 7);
    });
});
</script>
```

but i think it just works with divs and not links? couldn't get it to work at all, although something like this seems like the most logical solution.

and then there was [this page](http://www.ehow.com/way_5497693_changing-mouse-pointer-javascript.html), that shows a javascript just in the middle of an `<a href>` tag like this:

```
<a onmousemove=\"javascript:setElementCursor(this);\" href=\"#\">Set the cursor for this link </a>
```

but implementing a php post_thumbnail or something in there is already way too much for me. (what's up with the slashes anyways?)

any ideas?

Comment: Did you put that css in the css file or the sidebar.php file? Php won't work in css files

Comment: save the url in a hidden variable and write js function for hover to toggle the cursor to the thumbinail and default

Answer (score 0):

Can't imagine why would you want to do what you want, but try this:

IN header.php

```
<?php
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'YOUR_THUMB _SIZE' );
?>
```

Now your CSS which **has to be placed in header.php as well**

```
.sidebar a:hover{
    cursor:url('<?php echo $thumb['0']; ?>') auto;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed;
    border-color: blue;
}
```